Docusign Quickstart Issues
I've followed the directions for the quickstart:
Downloaded the zip for PHP > Auth code grant. I ran the composer install & launched at http://localhost:8080/public.
I was asked to grant authorization but upon being redirected with a 'code' included as a get param I get:

Uncaught Error: Class "DocuSign\Services\Utils" not found

If I take the arguments out of the URL (which included ?page=ds_callback and the grant code) I get the web form, but submitting it produces:

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Missing the required parameter $account_id when calling createEnvelope


This issue was fixed, should work just fine now

UPDATE: the underlying problem with the quickstart was resolved.
go to your local folder and under \src\Services add a new file called Utils.php
The content of this file is found here - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Services/Utils.php
Then try again and it should work
We will fix it so that the quickstart bundles this file in the Auth Code Grant Package.
You can also use the right-most full package (both ACG and JWT) and that should also work.
Sorry about the inconvenience.
